# create submenu in copy/paste menu in android

Tags: android, submenu

Is there a way to create a submenu in the copy/paste menu of an EditText on android?

I've called setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback on my EditText and can add items to the menu in the onCreateActionMode method, but I can't seem to create a submenu. Even when creating a submenu, the items I've added to the submenu end up in the parent menu. This happens both when creating the submenu and its children programmatically and when using a menuInflater.

Answer (score 0):

Share u code.For add in layout:

```
<menu> <!-----submenu----> 
<item> android:id"@+id/submenu1"
       android:title="Menu1"
       android:orderInCategory="1"/> <!-----first position---->

  <item> android:id"@+id/submenu2"
       android:title="Menu2"
       android:orderInCategory="2"/> 
</menu>
```

now u need in the main activity create the method`public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {`

Comment: So basically: add a regular menu item and show a new menu when it gets selected? Though it would kind of achieve what I want it's not a real submenu.